# What data structure is the most efficient for storage of metadata about files on a disk?

Tags: java, data-structures

I've been trying to find a suitable data structure that would allow me to store **data *about* files** that I have on my disk. That data would then need to be retrieved quickly when it is needed, as graphical output will be provided to the user using it just that data. I'm using Java for this project, so if there are already libraries that could help me with this, it would be great if you'd also list them here.

Comment: A TreeMap (Sorted based on node id or alphabetically) would do. The key could be Node id / FD and the value could contain a custom meta data object.

Comment: what about a database?

Comment: What do you require from this data structure? Should it be modified constantly? If so - how? (Additions/deletions/replacements) What is its size?

Comment: What data? how much of it? what operations are you going to do with it?

Comment: What filesystem is this? If you use Java 7+ and this filesystem supports the "user" attribute view you could store these directly "with the file" themselves

Comment: When you access files, they are kept in your disk cache.  If you access them again it is much, much faster.  I wouldn't keep in your process something you can easily retrieve again.

Comment: Data such as the names and sizes of files; it's metadata after all -_- . Regarding the size of it ,  I would presume quite huge amounts. I would need to allow the user to delete any files, search through the stored files as well as retrieve the data about files when I need to provide graphical feedback.

Comment: Search through the file is in the realm of [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval), and is not quite that trivial. Luckily - there are existing libraries (like Lucene) that can help you with that

Comment: The main problem I'm having is actually storing the data about the files I have on my disk in a different data structure that would allow me to retrieve it quickly; I can worry about the retrieval later though.

Comment: Efficiency depends entirely on the access patterns, and  not in the slightest on what's in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to `index` your files. You can do `meta-data` `indexing` and `full-text` `indexing`. `Full Text` indexes allow to `index` `text` of the `file` and in `meta-data indexing`, you can `index metadata of files` like `name of file`, `path of file`, `size of file`, `created date` and `last accessed date`.

`Benefit of indexing`: You can query into your indexed data. It can be used to build search capabilities for applications such as e-mail clients, mailing lists, Web searches, database search, etc.

For more detail click [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-apache-lucenesearch/).

Libraries:  [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/), [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).